# Lookup table with the query with arbitrary length without using a for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, hash, vectorization, lookup-tables

Say I have a lookup table as following

```
dt <- data.frame(name=c("jack","jill","sam","dan"),age=c(20,14,28,13))

  name age
1 jack  20
2 jill  14
3  sam  28
4  dan  13
```

Now I want to convert the following vectors to the vectors containing the ages of each element.

```
query1 <- c("jack","dan")
query2 <- c("sam")
query3 <- c("jack","sam", "dan")
```

I can build the following function(which I don't like) to accomplish this task,

```
get.age <- function(x) {

  answer <- list()
  for(i in 1:length(x)){
    answer[[i]]<- dt[dt$name==x[i],"age"]
  }
  ldply(answer)$V1
}
```

which gets the job done like this

```
> get.age(query1)
[1] 20 13
> get.age(query2)
[1] 28
> get.age(query3)
[1] 20 28 13
```

But I don't like the solution because it uses a for loop and some dirty hack. Ideally, I would want to do it more R-like using vector operations like this(which doesn't seem to work)

```
> dt[dt$name==c("jack","dan"),"age"]
[1] 20 13 #worked
> dt[dt$name==c("jack","sam"),"age"]
[1] 20  # not the right answer
```

The following solution works, but this requires the prior knowledge of how many things I lookup.

> dt[dt$name=="jack" | dt$name=="sam","age"]

```
[1] 20 28
```

I would like to know a method that can handle arbitrary size of vectors that converts the keys to elements without using for loop, if there is any

Comment: similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135102/looking-up-values-in-r

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a true lookup table, the result should be the length of the query and also deal with replication in the query. The approaches using `match(...)` are the only ones that do this:

```
query4 <- c("jack","sam", "dan","sam","jack")
dt[match(query4,dt$name),]$age
# [1] 20 28 13 28 20
```

This is because `match(LHS,RHS)` returns an integer vector of length(LHS) which contains the row numbers of the RHS which match the corresponding element of LHS.

The approaches based on comparison (==) will generally not work. This s because, when comparing two vectors, R tries to replicate the shorter one however many times are needed to make it the same length as the longer one, and then does an element-by-element comparison. So in the case of `dt$name==query1`, for example, the RHS gets replicated twice and the comparison is between `c("jack","jill","sam","dan")` and `c("jack","dan","jack","dan")`.

```
dt$name==query1   # RHS is: c("jack","dan","jack","dan")
# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
dt$name==query2   # RHS is: c("sam","sam","sam","sam")
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
dt$name==query3   # RHS is: c("jack","sam", "dan","jack") with warning
# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# with warning:   longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

On the other hand, using `LHS %in%  RHS` gives a result with length(LHS) and either T or F depending on whether that element is present in RHS.

```
dt$name %in% query1
# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
query1 %in% dt$name
# [1] TRUE TRUE
```

Note that it looks like `df$name %in% query1` and `df$name==query1` give the same result, but that's an artifact of `query1` being replicated twice in the latter comparison. See, for example:

```
dt$name %in% query3
# [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
dt$name  ==  query3
# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Answer (score 3):

You want %in%, it returns of logical vector that is used to subset the data frame

```
dt[dt$name %in% query3,"age"]
```

Comment: why did this get downvoted?, it is exactly what he is asking for

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of ways to do this, but I'll throw out one that I find useful. [`match()`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/match.html). [@jlhoward's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22244675/80741) goes into more detail and explains why my previous `==` examples were wrong.

```
> match(query1, dt$name) #these give us the index of the *first* matching value
[1] 1 4
> match(query2, dt$name)
[1] 3

> dt$age[match(query1, dt$name)]
[1] 20 13
> dt$age[match(query2, dt$name)]
[1] 28
```

You can also use `%in%` unlike `match` this returns `TRUE` and `FALSE` for the elements that exist in the comparison (be sure to get the order right for, `dt$name %in% query1` returns `TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE`, `query1 %in% dt$name` returns `TRUE TRUE`)

```
> dt[dt$name %in% query1, ][,'age',]
[1] 20 13
```

With [`dplyr`](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr) you can use `filter`

```
> require(dplyr)
> filter(dt, name %in% query1)
  name age
1 jack  20
2 dan  13
> filter(dt, name %in% query1)$age
[1] 20 13
```

Comment: When I try it `dt$name==query1` and `query1==dt$name` return the same thing.

Comment: @jlhoward oops, you're correct. I was thinking %in% and writing `==` (which is wrong) as you point out.